# Determine if a timestamp is between a range of timestamp pairs in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 3 columns: EventID, EventStart and EventEnd. EventStart and EventEnd are timestamps in the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" and EventID is a number.

I'm trying to figure out if any of my events overlap, and if so, which ones. I've been trying to write a formula for column 4 that says if the EventStart of this row is between the EventStart and EventEnd of any other row, print row (or 1 or EventID or whatever).

Is this possible? I've tried various IF, COUNTIFS and AND combinations but have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

If the limits are in **A1** and **B1**; to determine if **C1** is "in-between", just test that **C1** is greater than or equal to the `min(A1,B1)` and less than or equal to the `max(A1,B1)`.

[image]